# How do you measure memory allocation and limits in Metal?

Tags: macos, metal, metalkit

I'm building an image viewer based on Metal and currently experimenting with loading some rather large images (70,000 x 24,000 pixels). The image is being loaded into multiple `MTLTextures`, each of type `MTLTextureType2DArray`.

Metal appears to be creating the textures and allocating the required memory as Xcode reports my application using over 9 GB of memory. On my 13" MBP with 16GB of memory, I clearly don't have 9 GB of GPU memory for all those textures so I assume Metal is using system memory for the allocations?

However, when it comes time to perform a render pass, Metal immediately throws an `Insufficient Memory` error when I ask for the current render pass descriptor.

How do I manage texture allocations so that I don't exceed any Metal or system limits? Obviously at some image size I'll need to switch from loading the entire image into memory to a more tile-based approach but that's going to vary from one machine to another depending on GPU and RAM.

I would have thought that allocating new textures would just start failing at some point, but I appear to be able to allocate enough to cover an image of width 70,000 pixels and height 24,000 pixels (`BGRA8`), but that same allocation causes a memory error when the render pass occurs.

**Edit #1:**

I just realized that when using `MTLStorageModeManaged` for the textures, Metal only needs to update the video memory representation of the texture when I assign the texture to a fragment index during my render pass. If I don't assign all of the textures, then that my Insufficient Memory error goes away because, presumably, there's enough video memory left over for Metal to allocate a drawable.

That suggests I can have as much texture data as I do system memory, but I need to be careful how much of that texture data I access during my render pass to not exhaust available video memory.

---

**Xcode Console Error:**

> Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Insufficient Memory (IOAF code 8)

**Stack Trace:**

[image: Xcode Stack Trace]

**Memory Gauge:**

[image: Memory Gauge]

Comment: `MTLDevice` has the methods `recommendedMaxWorkingSetSize` and `currentAllocatedSize`. I don't know whether those refer to VRAM or system memory.

Comment: Interesting, I had overlooked that property. On my 13" MBP with 16GB of memory, it recommends 1.6GB for the working set. I've consistently allocated over 2GB of texture data for larger images and performance is more than adequate, though my fragment shader does nothing more than a basic sample. I'm still curious how to know when I've gone too far past the "recommended" working set and have requested so much memory that Metal can no longer provide a drawable.

Comment: @kennyc figure that out?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/MTLBestPracticesGuide/ResourceOptions.html) to determine the appropriate storage mode for a particular texture.

Comment: I used `Managed` storage mode since that's the default on macOS. That gives me a copy of the texture in system memory and a mirrored copy in video memory. But clearly I have a lot more system memory than video memory, so how do I prevent over allocating textures into system memory that cannot be mirrored in video memory? As it stands, I'm able to create 9GB of textures, but trying to render even one of them fails with an out-of-memory error.